# what is receiver account for and what is ds, in new version of eosio contract's constructor declaration

Tags: eosio.cdt, constructor

In the new version of eosio we declare the constructor as :

```
addressbook(name receiver, name code, datastream<const char *> ds) : contract(receiver, code, ds){}
```

How does `datastream` ds work here and what is the meaning of receiver?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but this may help people in the future. I know that the **receiver** is the contract that receives an action, and **code** is the account that owns the contract that is being executed during the initial action. I am guessing the datastream **ds** has to do with serialization and deserialization of data from the contract.